# change spriteBatch transform matrix witout Ending and ReBeginning

Tags: c#, xna, draw, spritebatch

I'm trying to draw transformed textures behind each other,but drawing in a different
spriteBatch.Begin(...,matrix);
spriteBatch.End(); 
section makes the layering not work, the last drawn texture is on the top.

Is it possible changing the matrix after the Begin method, or is there any other solution?

Comment: why don't you transform your textures using the spriteBatch.Draw() - Parameters?

Comment: it is not just simply rotation and movement, I'm rotating, replacing, rotating, replacing it in 3D by a matrix.
I don't think it is possible giving a matrix parameter to Draw(), is it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK is this not possible. I would recommend you to write your own spritebatch using the graphicsdecive.